# Como puedo igualar variables en JAVA?

Tags: java

Como se hace que A sea igual a B?

Haciendo long "a==b" no compila

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ejercicio2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            long a;
            System.out.println("Introduce un número entero: ");
            a = teclado.nextInt();
            long b;
            System.out.println("Introduce otro número entero: ");
            b = teclado.nextInt();
            c=..;
            long c=a;
            a=..;
            long a=b;
            b=..;
            long b=c;
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el codigo.

Comment: Estás confundiendo una asignación (=) con una comparación de igualdad (==). Lo que deseas hacer es una asignación de valor (=).

Comment: ya lo he editado

Comment: @ColoSans te has confundido y has hecho una edición a la respuesta de Luiggi en vez de a tu pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, a parte de confundir una igualdad con una asignación estás definiendo dos veces las variables a, b y c. Por favor, en vez de decir "no compila" dinos exactamente el mensaje de error que te sale, es probable que sea debido a que siempre que asignas un valor estás volviendo a definir la variable.

Comment: Tu problema es que ya definiste `long a;` y más abajo lo vuelves a hacer  `long a=b;` que solo deberías poner `a=b;` sin el long.

Answer (score 1):

**Esto es Igualar variables:**

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    long a;
    System.out.println("Introduce un número entero: ");
    a = teclado.nextInt();
    long b;
    System.out.println("Introduce otro número entero: ");
    b = teclado.nextInt();

    if(a == b){
        System.out.println("Los numeros son iguales");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Los numeros NO son iguales");
    }
```

**Esto es asignar variables:**

```
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    long a;
    System.out.println("Introduce un número entero: ");
    a = teclado.nextInt();
    long b;

    b = a;

    System.out.println("la variable A vale " + a + " y la B vale " + b);
```